# Runtime button always takes the last button's id on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

On `Page_load` I'm creating run time buttons. the post back condition is not being checked on page load, In Datatable_data different datas are present to be used as button's Id and Button's text part.

the code for creating button is

```
for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  btn = new Button();
  btn.ID = Datatable_data.Rows[i][1].ToString();
  btn.Text = Datatable_data.Rows[i][0].ToString();
  placeholderID.Controls.Add(btn);
  btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
}
```

and the click event is:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string str=btn.ID;
}
```

The button is created successfully but the problem is that on clicking any button out of the 5 buttons, `str` stores the ID of the last button created, but I want to have ID of the button Clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = ((Button)sender).ID;
}
```